# Handling JSON response with onSuccess, onFailure

Tags: android, json

I'm handling my JSON reponse with onSuccess and onFailure so far, this way:

```
    new JsonHttpResponseHandler() {

                        public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, JSONObject response) {
 Toast.makeText(gameInfo.this, "Works great",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            mProgress.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        }

                        public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, Throwable throwable, JSONObject error) {

                            Toast.makeText(gameInfo.this, "Error #" + statusCode + ":" + error, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                            //setContentView(R.layout.bad_connection);
                            //final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.retry);
                            mProgress.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        }
                    });
```

They both work great but I have an issue; When my API returns errors like "User does not exists" or "Map not found", my application keep showing the mProgress (Progress Bar) without reaching the success/failure methods.

Why is that and how I can show my API JSON result errors as toastes? Probably in the onFailure..

Comment: check the json object response if it's null do something, else do other like a toast message you have mentioned.

Comment: what is the exact error you are getting? can you post the log

Comment: I don't get error, the mProgress keep rolling

Comment: You said it doesn't reach the success/failure methods, so your progress bar remains visible, thats why your progress bar keep rolling. Maybe you have another callback function? Post your full class.